# Upgrading my Android Webapp (webview app) to native app without changing the package name

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I already have my Android app published on Google play store. But it is a webview app. Now I am planing to develop a fully native app. How can I keep the same package name for my new app, so that the existing users can update their old app. Is it possible to create and publish a new app(I don't want to edit the existing project)with same package name, also can I use the same key used for signing the old app in new one?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create and publish a new app(I don't want to edit the existing project)with same package name

No. Package id is unique. You  need to use the same package id for your new app and push it to the app store as update to current one. You must use the same sign keys too.